# How best to retrieve a record with related table items in using JOOQ?

Tags: mysql, database, jooq

First of I apologise for the title but can't think of a better way to word it.
Secondly I have the following table:

```
Profiles Table:
Primary Key: profileName <-----
                              |
Repositories Table:           |
Composite Primary Keys: (profileName, repository_name)
```

simulating a **1** - **n** relationship between the **profiles table** and **repositories table**.
I recently discovered [jooq](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/) and using it to retrieve and store the data from the db and have this code for retrieving a profile from the db:

```
profile = db.select().from(Profiles.PROFILES, Repositories.REPOSITORIES).fetch().stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getValue(Profiles.PROFILES.PROFILENAME).equalsIgnoreCase(profileName))
                .limit(1) //limit it to just the one result
                .map(this::convertToProfile)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```

works fine, but I am unsure of how to improve this to include the the retrieval of **possible repositories** found in the repositories table. That is to say repositories aren't mandatory rather optional to the profiles table.
My only option right now is to create a 'second cycle logic' to retrieve the repositories using the profile name before unmarshalling the data.

Comment: instead of collecting to list you can just get first result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Push operations into the database

Your query will be very slow as your data grows. Why? Because your SQL query only runs the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between `PROFILES` and `REPOSITORIES` tables, whereas the join predicate and the limit clause are then applied in Java memory.

The database never knows what you want to do with that cross product, so it runs this very slow query very dumbly. If you provide the database with more information by "pushing the predicate down" into the jOOQ/SQL query, the whole thing will run much faster (although, the stream result is technically equivalent). So, instead, write this:

```
profile = db.select()
            .from(PROFILES, REPOSITORIES)
            // WHERE and LIMIT are moved "up" into the SQL query:
            .where(PROFILES.PROFILENAME.equalIgnoreCase(profileName))
            .limit(1)
            .fetch().stream()
            .map(this::convertToProfile)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```

This query is the same as yours (not yet correct), but much faster

## Getting joins correctly

The above query still runs a cartesian product between the two tables. You probably want to join them, instead. There are two ways of joining in SQL:

#### Using the `WHERE` clause

Just add a `JOIN` predicate to the where clause and you're set

```
profile = db.select()
            .from(PROFILES, REPOSITORIES)
            // Join predicate here:
            .where(PROFILES.PROFILENAME.equal(REPOSITORIES.PROFILENAME))
            .and(PROFILES.PROFILENAME.equalIgnoreCase(profileName))
            .limit(1)
            .fetch().stream()
            .map(this::convertToProfile)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```

This is also called `INNER JOIN`, which can be written using the `JOIN` clause for improved readability:

#### Using the `(INNER) JOIN` clause:

Most people will find this syntax more readable, because `JOIN` predicates are clearly separated from "ordinary" predicates:

```
profile = db.select()
            .from(PROFILES)
            // Join expression and predicates here:
            .join(REPOSITORIES)
            .on(PROFILES.PROFILENAME.equal(REPOSITORIES.PROFILENAME))
            // Ordinary predicates remain in the where clause:
            .where(PROFILES.PROFILENAME.equalIgnoreCase(profileName))
            .limit(1)
            .fetch().stream()
            .map(this::convertToProfile)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```

#### "optional" `JOIN`

In SQL, this is called an `OUTER JOIN`, or more particularly a `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN`:

```
profile = db.select()
            .from(PROFILES)
            // LEFT JOIN expression and predicates here:
            .leftJoin(REPOSITORIES)
            .on(PROFILES.PROFILENAME.equal(REPOSITORIES.PROFILENAME))
            .where(PROFILES.PROFILENAME.equalIgnoreCase(profileName))
            .limit(1)
            .fetch().stream()
            .map(this::convertToProfile)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```

Note that the list of `REPOSITORIES` will not be empty but contain a repository with all values set to `NULL`. That's how an `OUTER JOIN` works

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I retrieve the list of Repository records from the resulting Result/Record object. I haven't found anywhere in the documentation addressing this topic.

Comment: @DarkStar1: [`Result.into(Table)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#into-org.jooq.Table-) would be a good choice